# Is there a way to conditionally compile for Swift 1.1 and 1.2?

Tags: swift

The definition of malloc() apparently changed in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3)

In Swift 1.2 it's defined as

```
func malloc(_: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
```

In Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.2) it's defined as:

in Xcode 6.2

```
func malloc(_: UInt) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
```

This means that code using this function has to be changed depending on which version of Xcode you're using. I've been bouncing back and forth between Xcode 6.2 and the current Xcode 6.3 beta, and it's quite annoying to have to edit my code each time.

Is there a combination of #if statement and some sort of environment variable that would let me make my code adapt based on the version of Xcode/Swift? (This is probably a difference between Swift 1.2 and 1.1)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to conditionally compile for Swift 1.1 or 1.2. In your concrete case, `let mem = malloc(size_t(numBytes))` should work.

Comment: Ditto what @MartinR said. In some sense, there's no "need" to conditionally compile for Swift 1.1 vs 1.2 because you'll only every be able to deploy production code to the App Store with only one of them — 1.1 now because the other is beta, and 1.2 later because once it's released it'll deploy to the same OS/SDK targets as 1.1 did.

Comment: (In other senses, working with betas of new languages is admittedly kind of a pain, and ways to ease that pain would be good things to [request from Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com), especially if you have specific suggestions.)

Comment: using size_t as the type for the parameter was the ticket. @rickster, Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)*
I don't think there is a way to conditionally compile for Swift 1.1 or 1.2. In your concrete case

```
let mem = malloc(size_t(numBytes))
```

should work.

`size_t` is defined as `UInt` in Swift 1.0/1.1, and as `Int` in Swift 1.2. With the explicit conversion you make it compile for both.

Comment: @DuncanC: You are welcome! – But there are other differences between Swift 1.1/1.2 that might be more difficult to solve, such as `countElements()` vs `count()`.

Comment: I'll fall off that bridge when I come to it. For now my immediate problem is solved.

Comment: Is there a Swift Language Guide iBook from Apple for Swift 1.2, and a coherent description of the changes?

Comment: @DuncanC: There is no iBook for Swift 1.2 (as far as I know). The changes are described in the Xcode 6.3 beta release notes (available on https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/). There is also something in the Swift blog (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/)

Comment: There's no iBook for Swift 1.2 right now because 1.2 is beta. I imagine there will be an iBook when 1.2 is final. But you can look at the web version of the same content on developer.apple.com, and it even has a [revision history](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-ID459) that tells you what parts of the book have changed to address Swift 1.2

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything about changes to countElements() int Swift 1.2. Can you point me in the right direction Martin?

Comment: @DuncanC: The `countElements()` function has been renamed to `count()`. I was sure that I had read it in the release notes, but I cannot find it anymore, sorry!